# Divergence of Harmonic Series proof step clarification

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

I'm trying to understand the proof 4 of the reference link but I don't get the steps to achieve this sum:
$$
S_n  = H_{2n}  - H_n  = \frac{1}{{n + 1}} + \frac{1}{{n + 2}} +  \ldots  + \frac{1}{{2n}}.
$$
I somewhat undestand the conclusion, but I failed everytime I tried to reproduce.

May someone please detail it to me?

Reference link: [http://scipp.ucsc.edu/~haber/archives/physics116A10/harmapa.pdf](http://scipp.ucsc.edu/%7Ehaber/archives/physics116A10/harmapa.pdf)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$\begin{cases}H_{2n}=1+\frac12+\ldots+\frac1n+\color{red}{\frac1{n+1}+\frac1{n+2}+\ldots+\frac1{2n}}\\{}\\\color{blue}-\\{}\\H_n=1+\frac12+\ldots+\frac1n\\--------------------------\\H_{2n}-H_n=\color{red}{\frac1{n+1}+\frac1{n+2}+\ldots+\frac1{2n}}\end{cases}$$

Just a matter of carrying on the above subtraction, according to the definition of $\;H_k\;$ ...

Comment: I didn't think about adding the terms 1 / (n + 1), 1 / (n + 2), (...)
Quite simple. Thank you very much